# Extracting String Data from PDF Multi-Page Columns with Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I have some PDFs that are organised into columns that I need to scrape.  The problem is that each column is multi-page and isn't in the typical layout for columns, for example:

`******Column 1******************Column 2*************`

`Sombody once told me         Finger and her thumb
 The world was gonna          In the shape of an "L"
 Roll me. I ain't the         On her forehead. Well
 *******************NEXT PAGE**************************
 Sharpest tool in the         The years start coming
 Shed. She was looking        And they don't stop coming
 Kind of dumb with her`

I have tried using standard PDF scrapers like PDFMiner but it will just return a string that reads like:

Sombody once told me
 The world was gonna
 Roll me. I ain't the
 Finger and her thumb

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can try tabula (https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) for table extraction. Also this discussion can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533875/how-to-extract-table-as-text-from-the-pdf-using-python/47719296