# Python Camelot borderless table extraction issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-camelot

I'm trying hard to extract some borderless table as show in the below image which are from pdf files. I have installed python-camelot as shown [here](https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot) and is working fine for bordered tables only. Please find below details:

platform - Linux-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-24-Twenty_Four

sys - Python 3.6.1 (default, May 15 2017, 11:42:04)[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)]

numpy - NumPy 1.15.4

cv2 - OpenCV 3.4.3

camelot - Camelot 0.3.2[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to extract tables from this PDF using Camelot?

Comment: @VinayakMehta The code is nothing but as given in the example for the below link [https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot]. I have tried all optional params but none seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To improve the detected area, you can increase the edge_tol (default: 50) value to counter the effect of text being placed relatively far apart vertically. Larger edge_tol will lead to longer textedges being detected, leading to an improved guess of the table area. Let’s use a value of 500.

```
>>> tables = camelot.read_pdf('edge_tol.pdf', flavor='stream', edge_tol=500)
>>> camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='contour')
>>> plt.show()
>>> tables[0].df
```

Comment: https://readthedocs.org/projects/camelot-py/downloads/pdf/master/
genius! just putting up the link to the info in the pdf docs

Answer (score 7):

Camelot uses lattice by default which relies on clear lines dividing the cells.

For tables without lines you want to use stream:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('your_file_name.pdf', flavor = 'stream')
```

Comment: This did not work for some of the tables which has hidden borders

Comment: You have to pass table and column dimensions. @allahbaksh

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that might help is setting the `table_areas` explicitely, e.g. to the size of the page :

```
# A4 portrait, MediaBox[0 0 595 842]
tables = camelot.read_pdf("filename.pdf", table_areas=["0,842,595,0"])
```

You can find the size of the area either throug Camelot’s [visual debugging](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#visual-debugging) features, or by opening the PDF with a text editor and checking for MediaBox or CropBox dimensions (beware that they don’t use the same coordinates convention).