# How i can extract only text without tables inside a pdf file using PDFplumber?

Tags: python, pdf, text, nlp

I want to process some pdf files using a NLP module, then I want to clean those files from all existing tables.

this is the code for extracting tables using pdfplumber

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open("file.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[1]
table=page.extract_table()
```

but I want to inverse the operation to extract text only

Comment: Hi @medensa, I also need the answer for same problem. Could you please share what you did eventually?

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`, the library used in this answer.

1. load the `Document`
2. you need to define a `LocationFilter`

A `LocationFilter` does pretty much what it says on the tin. It will listen to parsing events (like "render text" or "change font to") but it will only allow those to come through that fall within a given boundary.

Keep in mind the origin in PDF coordinates is at the lower left corner.
The `LocationFilter` in this example will therefor match only text in the lower left corner of the page.

3. Add a `SimpleTextExtraction` to the `LocationFilter`

The next question is "what is the `LocationFilter` going to pass events to?"
In this case, you can start by trying a `SimpleTextExtraction`.

**Putting it all together:**

```
l0 = LocationFilter(0, 0, 100, 100)

l1 = SimpleTextExtraction()
l0.add_listener(l1)

doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])
```

After the Document has loaded, you can ask the `SimpleTextExtraction` for all the text on a given `Page`.

```
l1.get_text(0)
```

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/)
There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with images.

Answer (score -2):

Do you really have to stick to the pdfplumber?.
If not, I can suggest a better solution, use tabula instead.
Here is an answer to a similar question you can check out: [tabula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050405/2081218)

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link to an external site. At least show how you'd solve this man's problem using tabula.