# How to extract table text from pdfs using pdfminer python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-parsing

I am looking for script to extract table text from pdfs using pdfminer. I have tried tabula but I am looking to integrate the normal text and table text to a database. Any ideas on how to implement this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can get some idea from this links

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/pdf-preprocessing-with-python-19829752af9f
2. https://gist.github.com/jmcarp/7105045

Comment: I have tried using pdfminer and tabula. Both are good for specific purposes. Pdfminer extracts all the text in the document where as tabula extracts only table related text. I need to get the table related text in the document.

Answer (score 0):

As many people provided in this link:
[How to extract tables from a pdf with PDFMiner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222918/how-to-extract-tables-from-a-pdf-with-pdfminer)

You can use Camelot to extract tables from PDF Miner.

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart.html#read-the-pdf